# Convertir un pdf a tiff usando tesseract

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs

Necesito convertir un archivo PDF a tiff mediante la librería [Tesseract.js](https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js#tesseractjs)

La aplicación será en HTML y JavaScript, lo que pretendo es escoger el PDF y a la vez convertirlo a tiff, lo que tengo por ahora es lo siguiente.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/naptha/tesseract.js/1.0.10/dist/tesseract.js"></script>
    <label for="fileInput">
        <div>Click this div and select a file</div>
      </label>
      <input type="file" id="fileInput"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Ese código me permite seleccionar un archivo desde la pc. He encontrado el siguiente video en el cual lo hace por consola [Using Tesseract-OCR to extract text from images](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QhJiOCwz-_I) me pregunto ¿si se puede hacer eso desde un navegador usando el código que muestro líneas arriba?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero que hay que aclarar es que Tesseract.js no es capaz de leer ficheros PDF, solo imágenes.

Partiendo de esa base, te hace falta añadir la acción de convertir el fichero que se selecciona en el input. Esto se hace añadiendole un controlador del evento onchange, que se puede hacer de varias formas:

1. En el mismo elemento input:

```html
<input type="file" id="fileInput" onchange="procesarFichero"/>
```

2. Añadiendo el controlador diréctamente al elemento input justo despues de pintarlo en pantalla:

```html
<input type="file" id="fileInput"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById('fileInput').addEventListener("change", procesarFichero);
</script>
```

Esto es necesario, pero lo que de verdad importa es la función que se define para controlar el evento, que tiene que ser de la siguiente forma:

```js
function procesarFichero(){
 var name = document.getElementById('fileInput');
 if(name != null && name.files != null && name.files.length==1){
  var file = name.files.item(0);
  //alert('Name: ' + file.name);
  //alert('Size: ' + file.size);
  //alert('Type: ' + file.type);
  Tesseract.recognize(file).progress(function(message){
  console.log('Progress is: ', message)
  }).then(function(data){
   console.log(data);
  });
 }
}
```

De esta forma estarás haciendo uso de de Tesseract.js correctamente. Para mas información te puedes dirigir a [la documentación de Tessaract.js](https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js#tesseractrecognizeimage-imagelike-options---tesseractjob).

Aplicando los cambios sobre el código HTML que has dado, se quedaría así:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/naptha/tesseract.js/1.0.10/dist/tesseract.js"></script>
<label for="fileInput">
 <div>Click this div and select a file</div>
</label>
<input type="file" id="fileInput" onchange="procesarFichero()"/>
<br />
<br />
<span>Text from image:</span>
<br />
<textarea id="remoseTextarea" rows="30" cols="50"></textarea>
<script>
 var isWorking = false;
 function procesarFichero(){
  isWorking = true;
  checkInputs(isWorking)
  var name = document.getElementById('fileInput');
  if(name != null && name.files != null && name.files.length==1){
   var file = name.files.item(0);
   //alert('Name: ' + file.name);
   //alert('Size: ' + file.size);
   //alert('Type: ' + file.type);
   Tesseract.recognize(file).progress(function(message){
   console.log('Progress is: ', message)
   }).then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    document.getElementById('remoseTextarea').value = data.text;
    isWorking = false;
    checkInputs(isWorking)
   });
  }
 }

 function checkInputs(disableFields){
  document.getElementById('fileInput').disabled = disableFields;
  document.getElementById('remoseTextarea').disabled = disableFields;
 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola he podido cargar la imagen, pero noto en tu código que no estas usando un idioma especificado del lenguaje que se va a traducir de la imagen, por otro lado ¿que es lo que hace tu código?, he ido a console lo único que veo es que se ha obtenido la librería tesseract de la url que se pone como namespce.

Comment: Si has visto el video que proporcione en el minuto 5:02 convierten un archivo PDF a formato tiff, ¿se podría hacer eso por código desde el navegador, desde mi page?

Comment: El código que he añadido en la respuesta procesa la imagen con la configuración por defecto de Tesseract.js y muestra en la consola de Javascript el resultado, como se puede ver en la línea que dice "then(function(data){console.log(data);});". Está bastante claro de hecho.

Comment: Por otro lado, estas comparando dos cosas distintas. En el video se está utilizando una aplicación, que no tiene nada que ver con usar una librería en Javascript en el lado cliente. La librería Javascript funciona de forma completamente distinta. Lo primero que he indicado en mi respuesta es que con esta librería no se   permite convertir PDF. Aún así he completado la respuesta con la configuración correcta de la librería, para que le sirva a más gente.

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar en tu respuesta lo que traduciste de alguna imagen?

Comment: Puedes ver el resultado por tí mismo, probando el código que he ofrecido. He realizado un cambio para que se muestre en pantalla la información resultante taras hácer. He subido a esta dirección: http://acastles.com/Tesseract/ 
Un saludo.